# Use abcde to produce high quality flac and mp3 output with album art under Xenial?

Tags: mp3, codecs, flac, abcde

Xenial Xerus has a nice modern version of abcde:

```
andrew@athens:~$ abcde -v | head -n 1
This is abcde v2.7.1.
```

I would like to use this to produce:

1. High quality mp3 files for my portable player
2. Lossless flac files as an archival backup
3. Suitable album art download for *both* formats

Using the capabilities of Xenial's abcde to perform all 3 actions at the same time...

*Full disclosure: I was formerly one of the maintainers of [abcde](https://abcde.einval.com/wiki/).*

Comment: As I do not have the privilege to comment yet, just a small addition to andew.46's answer: `flac` is also a requirement to convert to flac: > sudo apt install flac

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The version of abcde under Xenial is quite capable but some extra applications are needed as well as abcde itself:

```
sudo apt-get install abcde lame eyed3 glyrc imagemagick cdparanoia flac
```

Now to create great quality mp3s *and* flacs *at the same time* (with album art also downloaded) the following simple commandline is required:

```
abcde -o 'flac:-8,mp3:-b 320' -G
```

abcde will ask you a few questions and then you can sit back while your CD is converted into 2 of the most popular audio formats today :).

*Full disclosure: I was formerly one of the maintainers of [abcde](https://abcde.einval.com/wiki/).*

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=535950 gives this apt-get command: `sudo apt-get install abcde cd-discid lame cdparanoia id3 id3v2`.  Is cdparanoia no longer required? I see cdparanoia referred to by the page at http://www.andrews-corner.org/abcde.html too.

Comment: Answering my own question above: abcde depends upon cdparanoia, so no need to list it.

Comment: @bgoodr Good to see you answered yourself :)

Comment: What does `-8` mean in `flac:-8`?

Comment: @Matthias, it seems to be:

 -0..-8, --compression-level-0..--compression-level-8
              Fastest compression..highest compression (default is -5).

Check `man flac`.